# mobile flutter application, NFC does not start session

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, nfc

i am using the nfc_manager pack age: https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_manager

so once my app reaches the " NfcManager.instance.startSession " part( third code line ) it just skips over it and moves on, I do not know what is causing this, the app does not crash or anything it just never works, can anybody who has worked in NFC before help?

```
if (scannedFingerprint!) {

                                  //context.pushNamed('STAttendance2');




                                  NfcManager.instance.startSession (onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {


                                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                      SnackBar(
                                        content: Text(
                                          'NFC reader is Listing!!!!!',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                                .primaryText,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 8000),
                                        backgroundColor: Color(0x00000000),
                                      ),
                                    );




                                    result.value = tag.data;

                                    if  (result.value != null){



                                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                        SnackBar(
                                          content: Text(
                                            'Scan is Successful!! Finally: ' + result.value,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                                  .primaryText,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 8000),
                                          backgroundColor: Color(0x00000000),
                                        ),
                                      );



                                      NfcManager.instance.stopSession();

                                    }

                                  });


                                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                    SnackBar(
                                      content: Text(
                                        'HOME PAGE!!!!',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                              .primaryText,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 8000),
                                      backgroundColor: Color(0x00000000),
                                    ),
                                  );



                                }
```